# php intl extension fail

Tags: php, windows, nginx, intl

My php extension `intl` failed.

The php.ini is open `extension=php_intl.dll`, and `php/ext` dir have file `php_intl.dll`. Copy `icu.*.dll` to `Windows/System32` and `Windows/SysWOW64`, but phpinfo() shows

> `not intl extension`

.

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: have u make any change in your php configuration ..??

Comment: No any change, only change the php.ini extension part.